# Arduino - About Data Types

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I am writing a delay function for Arduino to be used in a project. The reason is that TIMER0 (the default timer used for Arduino delay) is occupied with PWM control. The test code for the delay function is as follows:

```
int count;
unsigned long int sec;

void delay_ms (uint16_t millisecond) {
  sec = ((16000000/12)/1000)*millisecond;
  for (count = 0; count < sec; count ++);
}

void setup (){
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop (){
  Serial.println('a');
  delay_ms(1000);
  Serial.println('b');
  delay_ms(1000);
}
```

This setup simply prints a and b with a 1-second delay between each. It's working properly but before that there were other setups I used that did not work. The changes are:

- Declaring count as an unsigned long => This led to the delay function working properly but only for the first time.
- Declaring and intializing count as an int in the initialization step of the for loop => The delay function does not work as intended, at all.

Based on the knowledge provided by Arduino Reference on [Unsigned Long](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/unsignedlong/) and [Int](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/), I'd thought that they are essentially the same in this case. Therefore, I'd like to get some clarification in terms of how the data is processed by the loop as well as the delay function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged the question with `arduino-uno`, and the link you provide for `int` explicitly say that `int` on an Uno is 16 bits, with a range of -32768 to 32767:

> On the Arduino Uno (and other ATmega based boards) an int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767 (minimum value of -2^15 and a maximum value of (2^15) - 1).

Now `((16000000/12)/1000)*1000` (for a delay of `1000`) is `1333333`, which is *way* over the limit of an `int` (even an `unsigned int`). That means your `int` variable `count` will *overflow* in the loop and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What happens practically when `count` overflow is that it becomes *negative* (since the Uno is using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for negative numbers). Then you count *up* to zero and the possitive number until it overflows again, leading to `count < sec` to *always* be true and give you an infinite loop.

The solution is, of course, to use types which can handle such large numbers as yours without problems. Like e.g. `unsigned long`.

---

Oh, and stop using global variables. Both `count` and `sec` should be local inside your delay function. ***And*** stop making your own delay functions, AFAIK the Arduino framework should have delay functions you can use. Lastly, Arduino is programmed in C++, not C, although without the full and proper standard library (it uses its own framework instead).

Comment: In addition to overflow issues, one should avoid 32 bit arithmetic on a lousy 8 bitter, since such code will be terribly slow.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense to me but the code I've pasted above is actually the working setup. I've tried declaring `count` (as unsigned long) and `sec` within the delay function itself but doing so made the delay function malfunction completely. This is what made me write the question.
On the other hand, I'll take your suggestion on using the library instead.